# How to run sites in subdirectories with NGINX

Tags: nginx

My NGINX app looks like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/home-app.sock;
    }

    location /memory-match {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/mm-app.sock;
    }
}
```

the site at directory `/` works but the site at directory `/memory-match` gives an error that reads "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

I know that both sites work as switching the directories will still result in the subdirectory not working.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the mm-app.sock. The permissions must be set to read/write for user/group (i.e. `chmod 660`). For more see [this great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04).